# Stream Audio and WebCam Video through Radio Frequency

Tags: rf, communication, high-frequency, data

I and my friend would love to make a better communication system between us since his internet connection is not the best and neither is mine. We are 20 km away from each other.

Our project is to place a webcam in each other bedroom and microphone and stream it through radio frequency, then getting the signal on each other computers without the needing of internet connection, maybe just not on the computer but also on the TV, like if our bedrooms were somehow connected.

I'm new to this field, Radio Frequency, and electronics in general. I'm good at programming in various code languages but I've done only a few projects with Arduino.

I'm very fast at learning so if you tell me what to do, what components to buy, and what to study I'd like to start working!

Comment: if you're in the same building, do not try to stream with another way than IP, you already have all your needs, just use specific IP addresses for your streams (local network). So You might add Ethernet modules to your camera & TV streamer with uniq IP addresses for each device ... all the rest is pure software/firmware setup ; As you already know coding/programming it is the best way for you

Comment: no, we are like 20km away from each other

Comment: That sort of bandwidth over that sort of distance is impractical without an amateur radio licence; and possibly even with one; at least legally. Which country you are in is possibly important.

Comment: I'm in Italy, btw is there some sort of way to do what I want to do even without using rf ? like some other forms of communication?

Comment: Use a VPN to have a "fake" local network     if debt is suffisant. :)

Comment: @MattiaSapio not quite sure what you're thinking of. You could run a glass fiber over 20 km. That works in Italy, as much as it works anywhere else on this planet's crust. Guess who runs glass fiber backbone networks all over Italy? Phone operation / internet access companies...

Answer (score 2):

The internet is different than the radio spectrum: you explicitly need a license to transmit in any radio band!

With Wifi, Bluetooth and the like, you buy devices that are tested to only operate in so-called license-free bands, where an exception to that rule exist.

Since you're not a radio engineer, you'd not start by trying to build a device that fits into the legal framework of Italy / the EU / ITU region 1 (hint: it's hard to do that, also, such devices are expensive to build in single quantities).

Instead, you'd use an existing system (e.g. Wifi routers) to connect.

You've just added this comment:

> We are 20 km away from each other.

Not going to happen, even if you *were* a radio engineer: To transmit live video, you need many bits per second.

To transmit many bits per second, you need good signal-to-noise ratio at the receiver.

To get good signal-to-noise ratio at the receiver, you need much transmit power to bridge 20 km. (There's mathematical bounds on that – nothing you can do to cheat that!)

That much power is not allowed in the license-free bands.

So, this is impossible to achieve.

Your cheapest option and best bet is getting a license for a point-to-point microwave link, and stock equipment for that. That's going to include a high tower, and at least 1000€ in RF equipment (very likely more).

Guess who has such licenses, equipment and towers? Companies operating mobile phone networks. They, for a relatively low price, sell you access to their network :)

Comment: Well thank you, i'm not gonna do that ;D

Comment: The license free bands allow milliwatts, enough for a few metres range; maybe 100m for sufficiently small bandwidth (not video!)